# maze recursion solving python

Tags: python, recursion, maze

I need to solve a maze using a recursive algorihm.however ,I get an index error whenever I try to solve the maze if there is an empty path.I think that the moving doesnt stop untill it exceeds the boundaries .any ideas ? I will post part of my code which solve the maze

```
    def find_exits(self, start_row, start_col) :#depth) -> bool:
        """Find and save all exits into `self._exits` using recursion, save
        the maximum recursion depth into 'self._max_recursion_depth' and mark the maze.

        An exit is an accessible from S empty cell on the outer rims of the maze.

        Args:
            start_row (int): row to start from. 0 represents the topmost cell.
            start_col (int): column to start from; 0 represents the leftmost cell.
            depth (int): Depth of current iteration.

        Raises:
            ValueError: If the starting position is out of range or not walkable path.
        """


        # base case
        if start_row < 0 or start_row >= self._row_range or start_col < 0 or start_col >= self._col_range :
           raise ValueError("Starting position is out of range ")

        if   self._maze[start_row][start_col] == OBSTACLE:
           raise ValueError("Starting position is not a valid path.")
        else:
            self._maze[start_row][start_col] = START


        if self._maze[start_row][start_col] == EXIT and self._maze[start_row][start_col] != OBSTACLE :
                self._exits.append((start_row, start_col))
                return True

        self._maze[start_row][start_col] = VISITED
        for r, c in [
           (0, 1) ,#East
           (1, 1) , #SOUTHEAST
           (1, 0) ,#SOUTH
           (1,-1),#southwest
           (0,-1),#west
           (-1,-1),#northwest
           (-1,0) ,#north
           (-1,1) ,#northeast
        ]:
                # set new position to neighbor
                new_row, new_col = start_row + r, start_col  + c

             
                if  self._maze[new_row][new_col] == PATH:
                    self._maze[new_row][new_col] = VISITED
                    self.find_exits(new_row, new_col)
```

I always get this error: [Previous line repeated 27 more times]

```
  File "C:\Users\alime\OneDrive\Desktop\JKU\A and Ds Ass\ass 3\my_maze.py", line 83, in find_exits
    self._maze[new_row][new_col] == PATH:
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what if your current location is at column 0 and you try to go left? what if you are in the bottom row and try to go down? you have to check that `new_col` and `new_row` are valid locations before using them to access the maze.

Comment: Please note that python arrays start at 0 index.  Please check all your input values and ensure your ```new_row``` and ```new_col``` are within the range.

Comment: my indexings are correct and within the range,I made some print statements.The problem that it finds all the exits untill its out of the maze boundaries

Comment: It seems obvious that `new_col` is out of range.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

This code is a disaster, consider:

```
    if   self._maze[start_row][start_col] == OBSTACLE:
       raise ValueError("Starting position is not a valid path.")
    else:
        self._maze[start_row][start_col] = START

    if self._maze[start_row][start_col] == EXIT and self._maze[start_row][start_col] != OBSTACLE :
            self._exits.append((start_row, start_col))
            return True
```

If you reach the second `if` statement, then `maze[start_row][start_col]` has a value of `START`, so the second `if` statement, always fails. The indexing problem is here:

```
new_row, new_col = start_row + r, start_col  + c

if  self._maze[new_row][new_col] == PATH:
    self._maze[new_row][new_col] = VISITED
    self.find_exits(new_row, new_col)
```

The `find_exits()` recursive call will check if `new_row` and `new_col` are valid, but you use them as indicies *twice* before that call, so you're potentially using invalid values in your array indexing!

Finally, `find_exits()` either returns `True`, throws an error, or returns `None`.  It needs to be more consistent.